# Keycloak user chooses OTP or SMS

Tags: keycloak

I want to add a question into the Keycloak auth flow after the user’s name and pw have been authenticated to ask what type of two factor authentication they prefer. The choices are OTP or SMS. If the user has already made the choice before, I will skip the question and continue to either OTP or SMS authenticators. Need some advice on how to implement this.

I have created an authenticator class that shows a template. Is that right? I have seen examples of creating a required action.

How do I skip the question if the user has already made his choice? I tried using returning false from configuredFor() but that just halts the flow with an error since my authenticator is set as required.

I plan on storing the user’s choice in a user attribute or possibly a cookie. Any thought on which is better?

As always, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Conditional authenticator to check the condition, there is an example of this in the server developer documentation: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#algorithm-overview

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Xiangjiaox' answer, result should be like this.

[image]